# How do I write a android service that updates my database on the server?

Tags: android, service

I am new to android, can anybody suggest me code to write a service that updates my database (which is on the server) every 15 minutes with the location updates.
It would be of great help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. use [kitlocate](http://www.kitlocate.com/) SDK.
2. follow [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/) tutorial for scheduling repeating tasks using alarmMannager

Comment: Thanku so much for ur suggestions :)